# Difference between pocket and absolute veto in the context of Indian constitution

Tags: constitutional-law, india, indian-constitutional-law

> The pocket of Indian President is bigger than that of US President

Meaning that the Indian President can keep a bill pending for infinite time then what is the difference between absolute veto, where he withholds the bill and a pocket veto.

Comment: Why I got a negative vote on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some standard books I figured it out myself

A bill according the Indian Constitution can have these following fates

```
President's Action              Impact on Bill        Veto
Gives assent                    Passed  
Withohold assent                Lapses                Absolute
Returns the Bill                Back to parliament    Suspensive
Neither ratifies nor rejects    Infinitely pending    Pocket
```

So the difference between Pocket and Absolute Veto is in former the bill doesn't lapse while in the later the bill lapses.